# How can I open a new window when the user clicks the button?

Tags: python, tkinter

How would I create a new window when the user clicks a button (still needs creating)? I have took some code out to make this shorter. I need a button creating and when they hit that button, a new window opens. I haven't created the button because the button has to be linked to the new window. Please help

```
My imports...

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # call start to initialize to create the UI elemets
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.master.title("E-mail Extranalyser")
        self.now = datetime.datetime.now()

        tkinter.Label(
            self.master, text=label01).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.W)


        # CREATE A TEXTBOX
        self.filelocation = tkinter.Entry(self.master)
        self.filelocation["width"] = 60
        self.filelocation.focus_set()
        self.filelocation.grid(row=0, column=1)


        # CREATE A BUTTON WITH "ASK TO OPEN A FILE"
        # see: def browse_file(self)
        self.open_file = tkinter.Button(
            self.master, text="Browse...", command=self.browse_file)
        # put it beside the filelocation textbox
        self.open_file.grid(row=0, column=2)

        # now for a button
        self.submit = tkinter.Button(
            self.master, text="Execute!", command=self.start_processing,
            fg="red")
        self.submit.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=tkinter.W)

    def start_processing(self):
        #code here


    def browse_file(self):
        # put the result in self.filename
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open a file...")

        # this will set the text of the self.filelocation
        self.filelocation.insert(0, self.filename)

root = tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008359/python-3-and-tkinter-opening-new-window-by-clicking-the-button

Comment: I have and it didnt help much

Comment: Actually, the linked question answers it quite well. Just create a `Toplevel` window. And what do you mean by "I haven't created the button because the button has to be linked to the new window"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Toplevel](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) to open a new one. Modify your code as shown below.

```
self.NewWindow = tkinter.Button(self.master, 
                                text="New Window", 
                                command=self.CreateNewWindow)

 def CreateNewWindow(self):
     self.top = tkinter.Toplevel()
     self.top.title("title")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBUpjijYtCk. Working through this tutorial would probably help you but this specific video shows how to work with multiple pages.

Something like this:

```
    from tkinter import *

    class Sample(Tk):
        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
            Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            container = Frame(self)
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

            self.frames = {}

            for F in (MainPage, OtherPage):
                frame=F(container, self)
                self.frames[F]=frame
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame(MainPage)

        def show_frame(self, page):
            frame = self.frames[page]
            frame.tkraise()

    class MainPage(Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            Label(self, text="Start Page").pack()
            Button(self, text="other page?", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(OtherPage)).pack()

    class OtherPage(Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            Label(self, text="Next Page").pack()
            Button(self, text="back", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(MainPage)).pack()

    app = Sample()
    app.mainloop()
```